# Complexity of algorithm (asymptotic)

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o

Can someone confirm me that the complexity of this algorithm is O(n^2)?

```
a = 0
b = 0
c = n
while (b <= c)
{
    for (j = b; j<=c; j++)
    {
        a = j * j -2 * j + 3
    }
    b = b + 3
    c = c + 2
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inner loop executes `c - b + 1` times. Each execution of the inner loop body `a = j * j -2 * j + 3` takes constant (bounded) time (assuming we're dealing with fixed-width integer types, otherwise it would depend on the multiplication algorithm used [and addition, but that's hard to implement in a way that multiplication is faster]), so the execution of the body of the outer loop is `O(d)` (`Θ(d)` even), where `d = c - b + 1`.

The updates of the variables controlling the outer loop

```
b = b + 3
c = c + 2
```

decrease the difference `c - b` by 1 in each execution of the outer loop's body, hence the outer loop is executed `n+1` times, and you have a total of `O(n²)`, since

```
 n                   n+1
 ∑ (n+2k - (3k) +1) = ∑ j = (n+1)(n+2)/2
k=0                  j=1
```

It even is `Θ(n²)`, unless the compiler optimises and sets all variables to their final values directly.

---

Answer for original question with typo:

The inner loop

```
for (j = b; j==c; j++)
```

will execute either once - when `b == c` or not at all, so the body of the outer loop is `O(1)`. The updates in the outer loop

```
b = b + 3
c = c + 2
```

mean that the difference `c-b` decreases by 1 each time the loop body is executed, so

```
b = 0
c = n
while (b <= c)
```

will execute `n+1` times - total: `O(n)`.

Comment: thanks for the quick help! but i made a typo, its j<=c not j==c

Comment: Ah, okay, in that case, I'll update my answer, but can already confirm that you're right, `O(n²)` it is.

Answer (score 2):

```
b = b + 3
c = c + 2
```

makes it so that b catches up to c by one each iteration of the outer loop. This implies the outer loop runs n+1 = O(n) times since they are initially n from each other.

The inner loop executes (c - b + 1) times. We know that they are initially n apart, and get closer by 1 each iteration of the outer loop.

Looking at the number of times the inner loop runs, it would look something like: (n, n-1, n-2, ..., 1) and in total

```
1 + 2 + ... + n = (n)(n+1)/2  = O(n^2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Each time your outer loop

```
while(b <= c)
```

executes, b and c become closer by 1 than before.  However, b and c start off at a distance n apart, so your inner for loop starts by executing n+1 times, then it executes n times, then it executes n-1 times, and so forth, until it finally executes 1 time and then your program finishes.  Thus your running time is proportional to

(n+1) + n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 1

and you can look up sum of increasing integers formula to see that this summation is equal to

(n+2)(n+1)/2 = O(n^2)

so your running time is O(n^2)